Black flash issue when toggle the visibility of symbol pin on azure map
So, I created a Vue project and added the azure-maps-control
npm install azure-maps-control

added the css in main.ts
import "azure-maps-control/dist/atlas.min.css";

Now, this is how I load the pins once map is ready
const labelId = 'label-'+r.pinname;
await map?.imageSprite.add(labelId, icons.Label.replace("{stroke}", r.pincolor));
await map?.imageSprite.createFromTemplate(r.pinname, 'marker-thick', r.pincolor, '#fff');
const stops = r.stops.map(m => m.coordinates);
stops.forEach(coord => {
  var dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
  map?.sources.add(dataSource);

  var shape = new atlas.Shape(new atlas.data.Point(coord), r.pinname);
  dataSource.add(shape);

  const symbolLayerLabel = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(dataSource, '', {
    iconOptions: {
      image: labelId,
      allowOverlap: true,
      ignorePlacement: true
    },
  });
  map?.layers.add(symbolLayerLabel);

  const symbolLayer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(dataSource, '', {
    iconOptions: {
      image: r.pinname,
      allowOverlap: true,
      ignorePlacement: true
    },
    textOptions: {
      allowOverlap: true,
      ignorePlacement: true,
      anchor: 'top',
      textField: r.pinname,
      offset: [0, -3.9],
      size: 13
    }
  });
  map?.layers.add(symbolLayer);

  dataSources.value.push(dataSource);
  symbolLayers.value.push(symbolLayer);
});

Then I created a function to toggle the visibility of that pins
symbolLayers.value.forEach(layer => {
  const opts = layer.getOptions() as LayerOptions;
  if (opts.iconOptions.image==pinname) {
    layer.setOptions({visible: visible});
    return;
  }
});

So there's a click button on the top left of this screenshot where I use the function for toggle the visibility of pins.

Did I miss anything?

You are using an empty string ('') for the layer ID in both SymbolLayer additions, this could cause conflicts or unintended behavior.

How you are toggling the visibility of symbol pin on azure map with image or URL?

You are creating a new DataSource for every pin, which is unnecessary and inefficient.


Black flash issue when toggle the visibility of symbol pin on azure map

The black flash occurs because adding/removing or manipulating layers at scale triggers frequent redraws or re-renders of the map.
You are creating a new DataSource for every pin and two SymbolLayers per pin (one for label and one for the marker), which adds complexity and rendering overhead.
Group all pins under a single DataSource.

One layer for the marker icon and one for the label. Instead of adding multiple layers, we filter the shapes using their properties.

Revised code:
const dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
map?.sources.add(dataSource);

// Add all pins to a single DataSource
r.stops.forEach(coord => {
  const shape = new atlas.Shape(new atlas.data.Point(coord), {
    id: r.pinname,
    labelColor: r.pincolor,
    iconColor: r.pincolor
  });
  dataSource.add(shape);
});

// Add SymbolLayer for icons
const symbolLayer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(dataSource, null, {
  iconOptions: {
    image: 'marker-thick',
    allowOverlap: true,
    ignorePlacement: true
  }
});
map?.layers.add(symbolLayer);

// Add SymbolLayer for labels
const symbolLayerLabel = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(dataSource, null, {
  textOptions: {
    textField: ['get', 'id'],
    anchor: 'top',
    offset: [0, -3.9],
    size: 13
  },
  iconOptions: {
    allowOverlap: true,
    ignorePlacement: true
  }
});
map?.layers.add(symbolLayerLabel);

// Toggle visibility function
function togglePinVisibility(pinname: string, visible: boolean) {
  const filter = visible
    ? ['==', ['get', 'id'], pinname] // Show specific pin
    : ['!=', ['get', 'id'], pinname]; // Hide specific pin

  symbolLayer.setOptions({ filter });
  symbolLayerLabel.setOptions({ filter });
}

If you want to toggle visibility for specific pins, use the filter property to hide/show pins by their ID.
symbolLayer.setOptions({
  filter: visible ? ['==', ['get', 'id'], pinname] : ['!=', ['get', 'id'], pinname]
});

symbolLayerLabel.setOptions({
  filter: visible ? ['==', ['get', 'id'], pinname] : ['!=', ['get', 'id'], pinname]
});


['get', 'id']: Retrieves the id property of each shape.
Dynamically filters pins based on their id.

Result:


Thank you for the response.. will try to use the filter.

@Lacey try the above code & let me know if any queries.

I did try the above code.. and put my stops in one datasource and use the filter for visibility of desired pins. But still getting the flicker issue.

One moment, it seems the issue is coming from the instance of my map variable. I will get back to you once confirmed.

@Lacey, If you are re-initializing the map instance (e.g., calling new atlas.Map() multiple times), it can cause flickering. Check the map instance is created once and reused across the app.

This is how I initialize const map = ref(null) this cause flickering, I changed it to var map = null and use the filter when toggle the visibility of pins. It works great now. Thanks for the help!
